# Linear programming with uncertainty in parameter(s)

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Consider a linear program (in inequality form) where one of the parameters is not known with certainty:

minimize $ \quad c^T x $

subject to  $ \quad a_i^T x \leq b_i, \quad a_i\in \xi_i=\{\bar{a}_i+P_iu|\;||u||_2 \leq 1\}, \quad i=1,\dots,m . $

I.e., the $ a_i $ are known to lie in ellipsoids.

It is possible to rewrite the linear constraint $ a_i^T x \leq b_i $ as

$ \sup \{ a_i^Tx|a_i\in \xi_i \}\leq b_i $

The LHS of the inequality can further be expressed as

$ \sup \{ a_i^Tx|a_i\in \xi_i \}=\bar{a}_i^Tx+\sup\{ u^TP_i^Tx|\;||u||_2\leq 1 \} $

$ \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad \; \;=\bar{a}_i^Tx+||P_i^Tx||_2. $

However, I do not see why this last equality holds. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one direction, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality will do the trick.  In the other direction, you can always pick $u$ in the same direction as $P_{i}^{T}x$, so Cauchy-Schwarz is tight.

Comment: Thank you very much! So by Cauchy-Schwartz we have that $ |u^T P_i^T x| \leq ||u||_2 ||P_i^T x||_2 \leq ||P_i^T x||_2 $ (since $ ||u||_2 \leq 1 $). Also, the supremum, $ ||P_i^T x||_2 $, is reached when $ u= P_i^T x / ||P_i^T x||_2 $. Correct me if I'm wrong. @BrianBorchers